# looking for a way to retrieve the information from an <a href> tags. E.g. <a href="www.facebook.com">

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

I am looking for a way to retrieve the information from an  tags. E.g.  is there anyway to retrieve www.facebook.com? I am using c# and i tried using htmlagilitypack but i can't seems to find a method to retrieve it.

Would appreciate it very much =)

Answer (score 0):

I would ultimately use javascript in this case. Then you can target the dom object and reference the attribute "href". However in code behind, you will probably need to use a regular expression to mind out the href.